# Как сложить цифры разрядов числа?

Tags: c++

Например, есть число - 1204. Надо, чтобы оно сложило цифры каждого разряда (1 + 2 + 0 + 4). Как это сделать?

Comment: `x % 10` получает правую цифру от числа. `x / 10` получает число без правой цифры. С помощью этого в цикле проходите по всем цифрам...

Comment: Советую посмотреть на ответ olkhovich - остальные два из серии "*зачем просто и быстро, если можно сложно и медленно?*"

Comment: @Harry проверил ради интереса https://quick-bench.com/q/Wt_p1D7-EFhuakNlkJnG4PmfiH0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
int solution(int number) {
    int sum = 0;
    while (number) {
        sum += number % 10;
        number /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: @Cerbo зачем вы добавляете своё решение в чужой ответ?

Comment: @dIm0n затем, что на этом ресурсе правила позволяют это делать

Comment: @Cerbo нет. Правки для правок, а не для добавления своих вариантов. Если бы это был общий ответ, то другое дело

Comment: @dIm0n Правки не для правок, а для улучшения ответов, я посчитал правильным  добавить немного другой вариант ответа в этот же ответ, а не плодить такой же но с перламутровыми пуговицами.

Comment: @Cerbo в следующий раз не надо так делать. Если вы не согласны, то сделайте обсуждение на мете. Вот пример https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10693/398802

Comment: @dIm0n чего я не должен делать, объясните?

Comment: @Cerbo объяснил же. Не надо добавлять свой вариант решения в ответ другого участника без его явного согласия, если ответ не общий. Можно исправить опечатки, форматирование и подобные мелочи без согласия

Comment: @dIm0n Я добавил его же решение немного измененное, тем самым дополнив и улучшив его ответ, и по-моему я об этом написал.

Comment: @Cerbo зачем вы повторяете то же самое? Если вы не согласны, то сделайте вопрос на мете с обсуждением, стоило ли в данной ситуации делать правку. Добавьте ссылку на этот вопрос, ответ, мою правку и прочее. Если большинство согласится с вами, то откатят обратно. Спросите в чате, если лень писать вопрос и мне не верите

Answer (score 4):

Вот так вот:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

int main() {
    constexpr auto x = 1204;
    
    const auto s = std::to_string(x);
    std::cout << std::accumulate(std::cbegin(s), std::cend(s), 0, [](auto acc, auto x) {
        return acc + (x - '0');
    }) << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Я бы учел, что число может быть отрицательным. Ну и еще один вариант:

```
unsigned g(int n)
{  
    n = std::abs(n);
    if (n < 10)
        return n;
    std::stringstream io;
    io << n;
    n = 0;
    char t;
    while (io >> t)       
        n += t - '0';
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Раз тут начались споры, что быстрее... Эксперимент

```
unsigned int Hovsepyan()
{
    unsigned int sum = 0;
    for(int n = 0; n < Count; ++n)
    {
        n = std::abs(n);
        if (n < 10) { sum += n; continue; }
        std::stringstream io;
        io << n;
        char t;
        while (io >> t)
            sum += t - '0';
    }
    return sum;
}

unsigned int olkhovich()
{
    unsigned int sum = 0;
    for(int n = 0; n < Count; ++n)
    {
        int number = n;
        while (number) {
            sum += number % 10;
            number /= 10;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

unsigned int dIm0n()
{
    unsigned int sum = 0;
    for(int n = 0; n < Count; ++n)
    {
        const auto s = to_string(n);
        sum += accumulate(cbegin(s), cend(s), 0,
                          [](auto acc, auto x) {
                              return acc + (x - '0');});
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    {
        muTimer mt;
        unsigned int s = Hovsepyan();
        mt.stop();
        cout << "Hovsepyan() == " << s << "  for " << mt.duration<>() << " mks\n";
    }
    {
        muTimer mt;
        unsigned int s = olkhovich();
        mt.stop();
        cout << "olkhovich() == " << s << "  for " << mt.duration<>() << " mks\n";
    }
    {
        muTimer mt;
        unsigned int s = dIm0n();
        mt.stop();
        cout << "dIm0n()     == " << s << "  for " << mt.duration<>() << " mks\n";
    }
}
```

(полный код [здесь](https://ideone.com/uowrTg)) дает на моей машине (VC++ 2019) и на Ideone (GCC) следующие результаты в мкс:

```
                 VС++ 2019          GCC

olkhovich()         8324            6970
dIm0n()            19634           80521
Hovsepyan()      1310028          434293
```

Так что моя рекомендация - принять ответ olkhovich - остается в силе :)

Comment: Вы специально продолжаете писать непортабельные параметры для `main`, тем более когда они не используются? :) Мерять производительность 1 вызовом как минимум странно. Кстати, типы не совпадают в вашем коде и в приведённых ответах. Оставлю тут тоже https://quick-bench.com/q/Wt_p1D7-EFhuakNlkJnG4PmfiH0.

Comment: @Harry, по моему никто и не спорил что быстрее, очевидно, что лучше самый простой вариант, а именно, без всяких дополнительных объектов. Но знать о других вариантах тоже неплохо. Вариант приведенный от olkhovich,   давно не новость в ответах на сайте....

Comment: @ARHovsepyan См. комментарий от dIm0n к вопросу, где он приводит данные, что его метод с преобразованием в строку и суммированием символов якобы столь же быстрый, как и метод olkhovich...

Comment: @Harry,  да, я комментарии увидел.. Но и без замера очевидно, что это не так: только для выполнения std::to_string    уйдет время  не меньше  одного цикла   с делением и взятием остатка

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Ну, это понятно нам с вами... :-)